# Center 2 div with one image in the middle

Tags: html, css

Initially I had one image and on div where the image centered into the round corner div. Now I need two color with one outer div and on inner div. The problem now the image does not stay in the middle like my previous single div. Below is my css and how I call my html.

```
#redIcon {
 width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  overflow: hidden;
    border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ff0000;

    background-color: #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
#smallerPinkIcon {
 width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  overflow: hidden;
    border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FA58F4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FA58F4;

    background-color: #FA58F4;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #FA58F4;



}

.imgTest { 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 

    border-radius:5px; 
    overflow: hidden; 




     position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-top: -15px;



}


<div id="redIcon">
                        <div id="smallerPinkIcon">

                           <img class="imgTest" src="imgcc/g.png"  border="0">
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the inner `<div>` and the `<img />` have the same width and height you can try to align the inner `<div>` instead of the `<img />`

*Previous snippet removed*

Here is a fiddle with the demo http://jsfiddle.net/hT4DD/1/.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, you can try the following CSS. This demo gives border in each div which covers entirely the inner element. So the image appears to be centered both vertically and horizontally.

```
#redIcon {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 5px solid #ff0000;
    font-size:0;
}

#smallerPinkIcon {
    background-color: #FA58F4;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 5px solid #FA58F4;
    font-size:0;
}

.imgTest { 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}
```

Here is a new fiddle with the demo http://jsfiddle.net/hT4DD/4/.

Comment: Ok I tried but why you remove all this border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FA58F4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FA58F4;.

Comment: I prefer to maintain the image to be 30px but both the div to looking have the same thickness with one at outer layer(red) and inner(pink) what is best suitable measurement for it

Comment: I simplified the CSS, the changes I made practically don't change anything, is just a shorter way to write the same thing. Do you need keep this markup or you could change it?

Comment: What did you change actually now? I need to main the the outer div to be 50px by 50px.

Comment: I changed the border-width to 5px (instead of 10px I had it at first). Now the `#redIcon` div has width=50px and also height=50px.

Comment: Ok if I understand it well what you did is add 5 on the inner then add another 5 on the outer so that makes 30 + 10 +10 ? Am I correct? So how about the other codes like this one do I need -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ff0000; I am not too sure?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The `border-***-radius` rules you were using can be replaced with the one `border-radius` rule. Also, the `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow` rules make no difference to the final result, so I removed them so that the CSS is smaller and easier for everyone to read. You can use them if you want to.

Comment: Actually what is the this extra -moz-box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow does I have done reading is it for cross browser comptability? Yes agree your codes are much simpler.

Comment: Now the browsers support the proper `box-shadow` property so you don't need to use vendor prefixes. See here http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow what browser versions support it

Answer (score 0):

**smallerPinkIcon** display property to **inline-block**.

**redIcon** Add text-align property  and set it to **center**, dispaly property set  to **table-cell**, and vertical-align set to **middle**.

When you change size of divs the img will stay center vertically and horizontally.

EDIT: If you only want to center horizontally, dismiss *display: table-cell* and *vertical-align: middle* styles.

EDIT2: look now to my hints.

Comment: I this what you meant display:inline-block , text-align:center and display:table-cell vertical-align:middle. I tried but the smallerPinkIcon stay at top and does not come to middle of the redicon div